# Why does the animated text 'stutter' occasionally as it transitions across the screen?

Tags: javascript, animation, frame-rate, velocity.js

I've been trying to make a simple marquee using `velocity.js` that will scroll multiple messages across the screen one after the other.

I've put together a working example but I'm experiencing issues with the text sporadically 'stuttering' as it moves. 
Using the developer tools in Chrome I can see that I get a drop in framerate when this occurs but I can't figure out why:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be anything unusual such as high memory usage and the computer is doing little else.
The issue also occurs in both Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox so it's not a browser issue.

**How can I diagnose/resolve the issue with stuttering animations, or is this situation to be expected?**

The sample below should recreate the issue although as the stuttering is random you'd need to watch it carefully to see what I mean.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // WINDOW WIDTH
  var width = $(window).width();
      
  // MESSAGE QUEUE   
  var messages = [
    "This is the first message", 
  "This is the second message", 
  "This is the last message"
  ];
       
  // APPEND EACH MESSAGE TO CONTAINER AND HIDE OFF RIGHT OF SCREEN
  $.each(messages, function(index, value) {
    $("#container").append( "<div id=\"message" + index + "\" class=\"message\">" + value + "</div>" );
    $("#message" + index).css({left: width});
  });
  
  // START ANIMATION WITH FIRST MESSAGE
  AnimateNext(0, messages.length - 1);     
});
   
function AnimateNext(current) {
  
  // GET THE CURRENT MESSAGE
  var message = $("#message" + current);

  // MOVE MESSAGE TO THE RIGHT OFF SCREEN POSITION
  message.css({left: $(window).width()});
   
  // MOVE MESSAGE TO THE LEFT AND OFF SCREEN
  message.velocity({left: -message.width()}, 10000, "linear", function() {
    
      // INCREASE CURRENT INDEX
      current >= 2 ? current = 0 : current = current + 1;

      // ANIMATE NEXT ITEM  
   AnimateNext(current);
  });
};
```

```css
html, body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Times New Roman";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkred;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle in case anyone wants to fork it](https://jsfiddle.net/adb88ss7/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this issue using your snippet, so I can't know for sure, but I would recommend looking into (requestAnimationFrame)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame] -- it allows for more efficient/smoother animations.

Comment: You could try animating with transform instead of position left as it will reduce the frame rate:  have a read of this: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: @anied VelocityJS already uses rAF, so that's not really going to help anyone - it also handles when the tab is out of sight properly, unlike rAF which is paused.Most likely there's some garbage collection going on at that point, but can't reproduce to narrow it down...